# Format Preloader and reflash (mtk6582) Sp flashtools

Tags: bootloader, formatting, flashtool

The problem is that spflash tools says:

**"PTM changed for the ROM: It must be downloaded."**

The solutions are, download the preloader.bin (not work for me), and format all + download....

**but I want not format /system either /data** .....

I've try do manually format (except bootloader, system and data) but the problem is not solved .... Can some one help me?

---

### I have a Importart question

What happen If I manually format the Bootloader of my mt6582, If I do manually for example (it's for my phone), erases from (0x0000000000000000 to 0x0000000000c00000) >> (bootloader to begin of mbr).... Then I would like download the preloader.bin with spflash tool.

**Could it brick my phone?**

Note: I want not do a readback

Comment: I think playing with that could easily brick phone if you are not sure what are you doing, and if that isn't verified by someone else. Better wipe system and data it's less painfull just backup data you need

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Maybe you have reason.. Hey due, I've done a test with spflash, and he says "Error: Flash NAND was not detected !", do you know what file contain the NAND information? in a mtk??

Comment: I don't know that. What are you trying to do with sp flash, to flash stock firmware or what?

Comment: I try Download a recovery, but the spflash tools says "PTM changed for the ROM: It must be downloaded.", i want not lose the system and data... I am in a bootloop

Comment: erasing preloader, really!? happy bricking...

Answer (score -1):

@Milor123 when the flashtool say that "pmt change for the blah. blah.." the only thing you can do is to format(auto) your device through the  tool and then click download next step.it is the BEST way to do it and succeed with what you want to do with your phone. hope this helps you.